# getting table name from query laravel

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

How can I get table name of the query with merged collections

example:

```
$hotels = collect(Hotel::where('special_offer_status', '=', 1)->with('special_offer_photo')->get());
        $tours = collect(Tour::where('special_offer_status', '=', 1)->with('special_offer_photo')->get());
        $trips = collect(Trip::where('special_offer_status', '=', 1)->with('special_offer_photo')->get());
        $merged = $hotels->merge($tours)->merge($trips);
        return $merged;
```

$merged comes with no relation for the table